# dropdown in a gridview header

Tags: asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I have a wierd problem in my gridview.

Here's the aspx page with a dropdown list in the header.

```
asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainerType" runat="server" 
        ActiveTabIndex="0"
        Height="626px" Width="1259px" >

<asp:TabPanel ID="tpDisperseSchemes" runat="server" HeaderText="Types">


        <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID = "uplDisperseTypes" runat="server" >
<table>
    <asp:GridView ID="gvType" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
     AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id,UserId" 
     Height="152px" ondatabound="gvType_DataBound" 
     OnRowDataBound= "gvType_OnRowDataBound" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"

    OnPageIndexChanging="gvType_PageIndexChanging"  EmptyDataText = " No Record Found"
    PageSize="4" 
    <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="Type">
       <HeaderTemplate>
          <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTypes" runat="server" 
          OnSelectedIndexChanged = "ddlTypes_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
              <asp:ListItem Value="0"> Please Select Type</asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem Value="1">Type1</asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem Value="2">Type2</asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem Value="3">Type3</asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem Value="4">Type4</asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem Value="5">Type5</asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem Value="6">Type5</asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem Value="7">Type7</asp:ListItem>

          </asp:DropDownList>
          </HeaderTemplate>                            
     <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind(TypeId")%>'></asp:Label>
     </ItemTemplate>                            
  </asp:TemplateField>
</table>
```

Now, when I select a scheme from the DropDown, it refreshes and fetches data in the grid--works fine.

But, immediately after the data is displayed on the grid, the dropdown goes back to the first value "Please Select a Type" instead of remaining at its selection.

Thank you for ur help
Sun

Comment: Is there any line in your code behind that selects the default value of ddlSchemes? Also, there are two ListItems with the Value="6".

Comment: @rikitikitik: No, I haven't set a default value to this ddlSchemes dropdown

Comment: @rikitikitik: I corrected the ListItems. There is a value = 7. but the problem persists.

Comment: Are you binding the grid in Page_Load? Are you binding every postback?

Comment: @rikitikitik: could it be related to update panel, tab container. Edited my question

Answer (score 1):

Is there a specific reason why you would put a dropdown list inside the grid? Your problem would not exist if you put the dropdown outside the grid.

Comment: @i have the dropdown in the gridview header. This is for the user to select a Type

Answer (score 1):

Good link. Very helpful 
http://www.aspdotnetcodes.com/Asp.Net_GridView_Filter.aspx